# How do you find the interval of convergence for the following sum?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

The sum:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty 5^{-nx}
$$
I have tried using the ratio test and I got: $$-1 \le 5^{-x} \le 1 $$ which I thought meant that the interval of convergence was something along the lines of (-1,1) with either parentheses or brackets which I tried all 4 combinations of and none of those were the right answer.

Comment: $5^{-x}<1,$ then take the log on both sides.

Comment: The title of a post should not the first sentence of the body.

Comment: Have you noticed that it is a geometric series with ratio $1/5^x$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured it out finally. Starting with the following which I had fairly closely:
$$ 5^{-x} < 1 $$
You then take the log base 5 of both sides which gives you:
$$ -x < 0 $$
Finally, multiplying by the negative switches the sign and gives the final answer:
$$ x > 0 $$
Or with interval notation:
$$ (0,\infty) $$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the summand is equal to $$(5^{-x})^n$$Then we simply have a geometric series with the first term being $\frac1{5^x}$ and the ratio also being $\frac1{5^{-x}}$. So we want $5^{-x}<1$ so that this geometric series converges. Taking the logarithm base $5$ on both sides, we have that the answer is $$-\infty<-x<0\implies0<x<\infty$$

Comment: No, we want $5^{-x}<1$ (or $5^x>1$), giving $-\infty<-x<0$ (or $0<x<\infty$).

Comment: I finally found the answer and what @J.G. said is correct, I showed the process in my answer.

Comment: @J.G. I didn't see the mistake, thanks!